# Testing Laravel models with relations in repositories and phpspec

Tags: testing, laravel, repository, eloquent, phpspec

I have an EloquentUserRepository and I want to test its methods but I don't really know where to start from. Anyone could provide any light to this?

```
public function findByProvider($provider, $user)
{
    if (is_object($user))
    {
        $user = $user->id;
    }

    return $this->instance()->whereHas('socialProviders', function ($q) use ($provider, $user)
    {
        $q->where('name', $provider);
    })->first();
}
```

This is an example of the functions I would like to test. It's finding users that have one socialProvider, let's say, github for instance. The basic structure of an User that has social providers would be something like this:

```
$data = [
        'user' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'email' => 'test@test.com',
            'socialProvider' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'github',
                    'provider_id' => '00000000'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Setting this, how can I test the model based on this structure? Is it really needed to create a memory db, migrate and seed for this purpose or can be tested without that?

I am using phpspec because of the laracasts videos, but I'm not really sure if it is the right option... I hope some of you might help!

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about the class that the method findByProvider is a member of.

Answer (score 1):

Israel, I know this is an older thread, but this may help someone in the future. In your case it is better to use something like [Codeception](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel4) since you are using Eloquent provided methods. 
From my experience testing around Eloquent Models has proven to be very difficult to test. You end up writing the entire logic of the method you are trying to test within your test, which is not good.

Essentially you can assume that Eloquent was properly tested and that the methods behave as expected, your test should only assert that this method will return a specific set of data as you describe.

Testing this with Codeception will prove to be a much easier task and allow you to test various scenarios based on the various data states.

Hope this helps you and future readers.